# Link to stylesheets in django template

Tags: python, html, css, django, django-templates

I am working on a large Django site and am currently adding the html templates.

this is the file tree for the main part

```
C:.
+---forums
|   |   admin.py etc
|   |   
|   +---migrations
|   |   |   ...
|   |           
|   +---templates
|   |   \---forums
|   |           help-style.css
|   |           help.html
|   |           home-style.css
|   |           home.html
```

I have been using `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home-style.css">` to link to the stylesheet byt when i do it results in this error

```
Not Found: /forums/home-style.css
[22/Feb/2020 07:38:14] "GET /forums/home-style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2702
```

I have tried using `{% static 'home-style.css' %}` and `{% load staticfiles %}`
but they didn't work

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd suggest you read the documentation on how Django expects you to handle static files: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/ . You cannot put your static files in your template directory. They need to go in a separate `static` directory in your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'forums/main.css' %}">`

I looked into static files as `solarissmoke` suggested, for anyone else interested have a look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/)